# Google Cloud Endpoints Metadata Server Authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc

**CONTEXT:**

For a project I am working on I have setup service to service authentication using a service account for a gRPC API sat behind the Extensible Service Proxy (ESP) as per the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/service-account-authentication). For reference my authentication configuration looks like the following

```
authentication:
  providers:
    - id: google_service_account
      issuer: <service-account-email>
      jwks_uri: https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/<service-account-email>
  rules:
    - selector: "*"
      requirements:
        - provider_id: google_service_account
```

I then have a ruby client that reads in a service account key (attained through the GCP console) from disk and generates a JWT using the `googleauth` gem to be used to authenticate with the API.

```ruby
module Authenticated
  def credentials
    @credentials ||= Google::Auth::ServiceAccountJwtHeaderCredentials
      .make_creds(json_key_io: service_account_json_io)
      .apply(jwt_aud_uri: ENV.fetch('SERVICE_NAME'))
  end

  def self.service_account
    @service_account ||= StringIO.new(
      File.read('/etc/secrets/service-account.json'),
    )
  end

  private

  def service_account_json_io
    Authenticated.service_account.tap(&:rewind)
  end
end
```

Currently this is in a working state and the client is able to authentication with ESP.

**THE PROBLEM:**

Since implementing the above I have another client application needing to reuse the same API. This means having to generate a new service account key and mounting that into the new application for authentication. Eventually if I create more clients then having to securely store many service account keys is error prone and a potential security risk. Instead I'd like to use the GCE metadata server to generate the JWT from lets say the default compute engine service account (although I may use a different account later) and pass this through to the ESP.

What I have tried so far is to change the ESP authentication configuration as follows

```
authentication:
  providers:
    - id: google_service_account
      issuer: https://accounts.google.com
      jwks_uri: https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/<gce-default-service-account-email>
  rules:
    - selector: "*"
      requirements:
        - provider_id: google_service_account
```

and updated the ruby client to request a JWT from the metadata server as follows

```ruby
module Authenticated
  METADATA_SERVER_IDENTITY_URI = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?format=full&audience='.freeze

  def credentials
    { authorization: "Bearer #{identity_jwt}" }
  end

  private

  def identity_jwt
    http = Net::HTTP.new(identity_uri.hostname)
    http.request(identity_request).body
  end

  def identity_request
    Net::HTTP::Get.new(identity_uri).tap do |req|
      req.add_field('Metadata-Flavor', 'Google')
    end
  end

  def identity_uri
    URI.parse("#{METADATA_SERVER_IDENTITY_URI}https://#{ENV['SERVICE_NAME']}")
  end
end
```

This again generates a JWT however this time with the issuer set to `https://accounts.google.com` (as reflected in the ESP authentication configuration). However this time the client is unable to authenticate with the ESP reporting `Error: KEY_RETRIEVAL_ERROR`

**THE QUESTION:**

Is it possible to authenticate against the ESP using a JWT generated through the GCE metadata server? And what are the configuration steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the `jwks` key from the Google Cloud Endpoints configuration yaml it forces ESP to use OpenID discovery to fetch the `jwks_uri` that will be used to obtain the correct `JWK`. This can be seen in the [api manager configuration](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/1775d95306a21ae43d71ec20f633600074ab4119/src/api_manager/config.cc#L504).

Given the same issuer defined in the question (`accounts.google.com`) the code will generate a URL to https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration containing the `jwks_uri`. ESP uses the `jwks` specified here to verify a JWT.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the second case, the JWT retrieved is Google signed ("iss" is https://accounts.google.com) JWT, not the service account signed  ("iss" is the service account email) JWT. So the JWT URI needs to updated accordingly. 
The previous jwks-uri (https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/) only applies to service account signed JWT.

Comment: Thank you. This clarifies things somewhat